# Find the proportion of points that are won by player 1

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

> Two players are playing a sequence of points, which begin when one of the players serves. Suppose that player 1 wins each point she serves win probability $p$ and wins each point her opponent serves with probability $q$. Suppose the winner of a point becomes the server of the next point.
>
> (a) Find the proportion of points that are won by player 1.
>
> (b) Find the proportion of time that player 1 is the server.

I am stuck in how to find the transition probability. I feel like we need to define two Markov chains for the question (a) and (b). For (a) I feel like to define the $X_n$ is the $nth$ serves player 1 won. And $P_{1,1}=1-p$ $P_{1,2}=1-p$. Does it work? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HINT

I interpret the question to mean the players play forever, and "proportion" means the long-term average of the fraction (of points in (a), of time in (b)).

- Answer (a) = answer (b).  Can you see why?
- Given the above, you really only need to answer one question.  I find it more natural to think of a $2$-state M.C. where state $i$ represents player $i$ serving.  What are the $4$ transition probabilities $P_{11}, P_{12}, P_{21}, P_{22}$?
- Once you set up the M.C. the long-term average is just the steady state distribution.  Can you find that?

Can you finish from here?

Comment: Oh, I can get the $P_{11}=p$, $P_{12}=1-p$,  $P_{21}=1-q$,  $P_{22}=q$. So the stationary distribution is $1/2$ (doubly stochastic). But why the (a) is same (b)? I understand your MC in (b). So in (a), state-space mean points of player 1? But it does not a two-point state space.

Comment: Do you mean the (a) state space is $\{1,2\}$ which is $1$ player won but $2$ not?

Comment: Several things here: (A) Actually $P_{21} = q$ because the question said "player 1 wins each point her opponent serves with probability $q$".  so if player 2 is serving, there is prob $q$ that the next server will be player 1. (B) This M.C. is _not_ doubly stochastic! The row sums are $1$ (of course) but the column sums are not. And the stationary distrib is not $1/2$. E.g. imagine player 1 is much better ($p \approx 1, q \approx 1$) then she would win most of the points and spend a lot of the time serving.

Comment: (C) Answer (a) = answer (b) because we're talking about long-term avg. Suppose player 1 has won $M$ out of the first $N$ points, then how many times has she served? It can only be $M-1, M$ or $M+1$ times, do you see why? So in the long term avg (as $N \to \infty$) the two proportions are the same. (D) I would say for (a) the state-space is also "player $i$ is serving" which is equiv to "player $i$ has won the most recent point", i.e. same M.C. as (b). The proportion of points won (long term avg) equals the proportion of time she's won the most recent point. The same M.C. solves both problems.